# extract text from html mail odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I want to get the email body but not in html format . I have used Beautifulsoup and
    data = re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', html2) 
to remove the html tags but it didn't work I can't receieve email to applicant

```
def message_new(self, cr, uid, msg, custom_values=None, context=None):
""" Overrides mail_thread message_new that is called by the mailgateway
    through message_process.
    This override updates the document according to the email.
"""
if custom_values is None:
    custom_values = {}
val = msg.get('from').split('<')[0]
val1 = msg.get('from').split('<')[1]
val2 = val1.split('>')[0]
myString2 = msg.get('body') if msg.get('body') else ''
soup = BeautifulSoup(myString2)
data = soup.get_text()
defaults = {
    'name': msg.get('subject') or _("No Subject"),
    'partner_name': val,
    'email_from': val2,
    'email_cc': msg.get('cc'),
    'user_id': False,
    'partner_id': msg.get('author_id', False),
    'description': data,
}
if msg.get('priority'):
    defaults['priority'] = msg.get('priority')
defaults.update(custom_values)
return super(hr_applicant, self).message_new(cr, uid, msg,custom_values=defaults, context=context)
```

Answer (score 1):

please try re library of python for remove html tags from text.

```
  import re
  text = re.compile('<.*?>')
  message = re.sub(text, '', self.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) with good success for the exact same thing: stripping out the HTML tags but keep the data.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)
    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()
```

`strip_tags` expects a string containing your HTML content.

Comment: did you try it on odoo because it didn't work I still have the same problem once I update the code I don't receive email